# 'value' is not a valid managed object. in realm while storing list

Tags: android, arraylist, realm, local-storage

```
public class User
    extends RealmObject  {
@PrimaryKey
private long id;
@Index

private String name;

private RealmList<MessageDetails> messageDetails;
//getter setter here

}
```

**MessageDetails.class is here**

```
public class MessageDetails   extends  RealmObject  {
private Boolean isIncoming;
private String lastPosLeft;
private String message;
// getter setter here`}
```

**button click for update list**

```
 int   pos = myData.size();
            mDetails = new MessageDetails();
            mDetails.setMessage(etMessage.getText().toString());
            mDetails.setIncoming(msgInOrOutBoolean);
            mDetails.setLastPos(msgTypeOutgoingOrIncoming);
            
            myData.add(pos,mDetails);
updateMsgInRealm();
```

**update list **

```
 private void updateMsgInRealm() {
    Realm realm = RealmManager.getRealm();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            final User user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", mPref.getCurrentSelectedUserId()).findFirst();

            assert user != null;
            user.setMessageDetails(myData);

        }
    });
}
```

**logs**

```
e  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'value' is not a valid managed object.
    at io.realm.ProxyState.checkValidObject(ProxyState.java:213)
    at io.realm.com_example_dummychatapp_realm_UserRealmProxy.realmSet$messageDetails(com_example_dummychatapp_realm_UserRealmProxy.java:248)
    at com.example.dummychatapp.realm.User.setMessageDetails(User.java:54)
    at com.example.dummychatapp.MainActivity$2.execute(MainActivity.java:156)
    at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1493)
    at com.example.dummychatapp.MainActivity.updateMsgInRealm(MainActivity.java:149)
    at com.example.dummychatapp.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:217)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6710)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6668)
    at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:797)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26450)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Here `mPref.getCurrentSelectedUserId()` is `id` stored in `sharedPrefance`
i got error while storing `RealmList` .

please if anyone can help me store list in realm db, i tried some code but not work for me if any sample code which fulfill my requirement suggest me here.

Comment: I think you should not replace the whole list of user everytime you add one message(performance wise). try  user.setMessageDetails().add(mDetails); // pass mDetails to updateMsgInRealm. Similar  example:- https://dzone.com/articles/realm-practical-use-in-android 2nd example University<>Student

Comment: but i have  list of messages per user so. i need to store it as list or array-list or realm-list

Comment: Try  user.setMessageDetails(realm.copyToRealm(myData));

Comment: its show casting error

Comment: try casting it to RealmList<MessageDetails> like -user.setMessageDetails(realm.copyToRealm((RealmLIst<MessageDetails)> myData))

Comment: i try this                 user.setMessageDetails((RealmList<MessageDetails>) realm.copyToRealm(myData));  but its crash showing list cannot cast to realmList

Comment: ok..is it working now?

Comment: no man any other approach should i use ? please share if you have any reference code

Comment: you can refer https://dzone.com/articles/realm-practical-use-in-android 2nd example. Student<>University

Comment: Pls try if it helps you

user.setMessageDetails(new RealmList<MessageDetails>(myData.toArray(new MessageDetails[myData.size()]))); 

 ref:https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1278

Comment: thank for your reply but its did not work for me man........still  show 'value' is not a valid managed object.

Comment: thanks buddy giving your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

**hey i got solution after wasting my whole day man here i listed problem**

**here i did wrong**

```
enter int   pos = myData.size();
        mDetails = new MessageDetails();
        mDetails.setMessage(etMessage.getText().toString());
        mDetails.setIncoming(msgInOrOutBoolean);
        mDetails.setLastPos(msgTypeOutgoingOrIncoming);
        
        myData.add(pos,mDetails);
```

**use this **

```
                    MessageDetails mDetails = realm.createObject(MessageDetails.class);
 mDetails.setMessage(etMessage.getText().toString());
        mDetails.setIncoming(msgInOrOutBoolean);
        mDetails.setLastPos(msgTypeOutgoingOrIncoming);
        
        myData.add(pos,mDetails);
```

**and all you need to  put above code inside **

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {

       // here you need to use above code 

        final User user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", mPref.getCurrentSelectedUserId()).findFirst();

        assert user != null;
        user.setMessageDetails(myData);

    }
});
```